# PHP using empty, isset or is_null in a ternary

Tags: php, ternary-operator

My PHP is rusty and I'm struggling to figure this out. I'm working with forum software (SMF) and can't really tell the value of the variable I'm trying to check.

All members are assigned a `post_group` e.g Senior Member

Some users are assigned a special `group` e.g Moderator.

I want to set the variable `$memberType` to the `group` if there is one, if not the `post_group`.

E.g

User is Moderator and Senior Member. `$memberType = 'Moderator'`

User is just Junior Member. `$memberType = 'Junior Member'`

Here's what I've tried:

```
$memberType = is_null($message['member']['group']) ? $message['member']['group'] : $message['member']['post_group'];
```

I also tried `empty()` and `isset()` instead of `is_null` but none of them seem to get me a consistent result.

`is_null` only applies the `post_group`, `empty()` only applies the `post_group`  but weirdly not for my "newbie" class. `isset()` only applies the `post`.

Any way I can get a consistent result?

Comment: What you're doing is assigning  `$message['member']['group']` to  `$message['member']['group']` if `$message['member']['group']` is `null`, it doesn't make any sense to me. are you sure you don't want `!is_null`?

Comment: Your logic is backwards at the moment. You pretty much say: "Is the group null? YES, then assign the null value to $memberType, if there is a group use the post_group". So what you probably want is something like this: `$memberType = isset($message['member']['group']) ? $message['member']['group'] : $message['member']['post_group'];`. Now the code says "Is a group set? YES, then assign the group, if there is no group set use the post_group"

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed a `!` in your question. `empty` should work in your scenario. Acc to the man page of `empty`

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

So to sum up something like this should work.

```
$memberType = empty($message['member']['group']) === FALSE ? $message['member']['group'] : $message['member']['post_group'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is :

```
$memberType = empty($message['member']['group']) ? $message['member']['post_group'] : $message['member']['group'];
```

Basically is says (pseudocode):

**IF** `$message['member']['group']` **IS EMPTY**  :

```
$memberType = $message['member']['post_group'];
```

**ELSE** :

```
$memberType = $message['member']['group'];
```

---

> [empty()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

The following value are considered to be empty:

- `""` (an empty `string`)
- `0` (`0` as an `integer`)
- `0.0` (`0` as a `float`)
- `"0"` (`0` as a `string`)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty `array`)
- `$var;` (a variable declared, but without a value)